# Webjobs not logging to azure-jobs-invoke-log

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Previously, when I used the TextWriter to log messages in a Webjob, those got written to a blob container called **azure-jobs-invoke-log**.

Unfortunately, that container does not exist in the storage account which I am using with the update 0.4.0 beta.

Have those logs been routed to a new container?

Follow-up question - the logs which I have identified generally in Azure seem to be ordered by GUID, or at least some ordering which is not helpful to me. Is there a way of quickly finding a log for a recent event without having to scroll through pages and pages of a grid?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can definitely answer the question of where the TextWriter in the WebJob writes the logs to. My colleague has a licence for Cerebrata's Azure Management Studio, which makes looking through the blob storage much easier than the portal or the free Azure Explorer.

They are stored as blobs at in a container called **azure-webjobs-hosts** in a sub-directory called **output-logs**. That looks like **azure-webjobs-hosts/output-logs** in the portal.

I'm not sure what the sub-structures are in blob containers. I referred to it as a sub-directory, but it probably has some formal, *de jure* name.